# Drools Invalid credentials to load data from remote server. Contact your system administrator

Tags: drools, jbpm

Whenever I try to open process definition in drools , Getting the Below Error

**Invalid credentials to load data from remote server. Contact your system administrator.**

[image: Error Snapshot]

I have given all permissions to role permission to user but still this error shows up.

Comment: The error says your credentials are wrong, not your permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While many details from your problem are not clear, here is the bottom line of this issue.

You are logging into the business-central with user 'nithish'. This user, will be used in the remote REST requests to your kie server instance. This means that user 'nithish' needs to exists on the kie-server side as well - otherwise kie-server will not recognise that user, thus authentication will fail. He needs to be created there with the same password and same roles as are present on the business-central side. I would advise at least

> kie-server, rest-all,admin

roles.

Answer (score 0):

The server you've installed your business central on has no access rights.

Comment: On premise installation - use ./add-user.sh script to add new user on the kie-server and assign the correct role kie-server.
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4859751